# efficient way to sort in ascending and descending order on the fly

Tags: python, sorting, big-o

From the following code, I am using the function `generator` which creates random numbers and helps to simulate incoming data.

```py
from random import randint


def generator(n=1000):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield randint(0, n)
        i += 1
```

For sorting in ascending order and get only the lowest 10 records I use this:

```py
out_size = 10
out = []
for num in generator():
    if not len(out):
        out.append(num)
    else:
        for i in range(out_size):
            if num < out[i]:
                out.insert(i, num)
                break
            elif len(out) < out_size:
                out.append(num)
                break

print out[:out_size]
```

Is there an efficient and better way to sort the generated data?, how to doing in descending order. ?

The input is a constant stream, but I just need to keep the lowest and highest 10 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`heapq.nlargest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) and [`heapq.nsmallest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) functions; these use a heap to efficiently track largest or smallest K items for you:

```
import heapq

out = heapq.nsmallest(10, generator())
```

A heap invariant is maintained in O(logK) complexity, with K being the size (10 here); the `nsmallest` function creates a heap of size K, fills it with the first K elements, then pushes each next value onto the heap popping off the now-largest each time, in one operation.

Looping over N elements then makes the total operation O(N logK), while sorting would take O(N logN). Provided K remains smaller than N the `heapq` approach wins.

Once the generator is exhausted, the heap is returned in sorted order.

Comment: Does this works when data does not come from a generator, something like standard input?

Comment: @nbari: it works for any iterable. You can take a peek at the [`heapq` module source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py) if you want to implement this in your own loop, but a generator function can feed it best. If you are reading the source code: there are *two* implementations for both functions in the file; the first is the core algorithm which has a C implementation for speed, and the second wraps the first to add the `key` argument support.

Comment: to clarify something: maintaining the invariant (i.e. each push operation) is `O(logk)`, making the overall complexity `O(n logk)` (as opposed just sorting the final list and taking k lowest, which is `O(n logn)`)